# How to convert shape keys into weight bones?

Tags: animation, rigging, drivers, shape-keys, vertex-weights

Simply put I have a low poly model with little no skills in clean facial rigging so I use shape keys to give me a better output than what I can do.

Although I was able to setup shape keys and drivers for them, the model I am using is supposed to be used in a game engine (*Roblox Studio*) that doesn't translate shape key movement. Therefore I need a way to be able to convert my shape key movement into a vertex weight so I can attach it to some kind of bone in order for the game engine to be able to read the bone movement.

[Gyazo Video](https://gyazo.com/0c3bea9150ae2ff39a136480ed728753)

Right now the bone drivers I have only change the value of the shape key as it moves and as mentioned the game engine (*Roblox Studio*) won't register shape key movement. The game engine also doesn't register visual transform movement, It has to be attached to a bone in some way. Does anyone have a crazy plugin or odd way to magically make this work? I am willing to switch to different programs to get it done if thats what needs to happen.

Comment: Might be helpful to mention what game engine you are using

Comment: You can't reasonably do this.  You could make a bone for every single vertex, but that's well out of the realm of what I consider reasonable.  Otherwise, develop your facial rigging skills, or use a different engine.